# How to count tags in JSOUP?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a such html code:

```
<div class="date-item">
   <tr class="row" rel="id-256">...</tr>
   <tr class="row" rel="id-368">...</tr>
   <tr class="row" rel="id-495">...</tr>
</div>
```

How can I count the number of *tr class="row"* using JSOUP?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have `<tr>` in `<div>` instead of `<table>`?

Answer (score 3):

```
   String html = "<div class=\"date-item\">\n" +
                "   <tr class=\"row\" rel=\"id-256\">a</tr>\n" +
                "   <tr class=\"row\" rel=\"id-368\">a</tr>\n" +
                "   <tr class=\"row\" rel=\"id-495\">a</tr>\n" +
                "</div>";
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "",  Parser.xmlParser());
   Elements els = doc.select("tr.row");
   System.out.println(els.size());
```

Comment: It seems that Jsoup will not interpret `<tr>` correctly if they are not inside `<table>`. Does this code work for you?

Comment: let me open an ide :)

Comment: So I was right, standard HTML parser will not accept this as valid HTML. XML parser is required here. +1 for showing how make JSoup use XML parser.